# Scrape dynamic flight information

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

I would like to scrape off the top 5 (dynamic) arriving flights AND departing flights (another tab on the main page schiphol.nl). For the arriving flights I typed:

```
url = "www.schiphol.nl"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
xpathSApply(doc, "//ul[@class='flights']//tr", xmlValue)
```

Gives me result NULL
Please help me to get the 5 displayed arriving flights in a df + the 5 departing ones in other or even better all in one DF. thnkx

In the HTML structure I see that the Unstructured List for arriving flights I need has the following specs:

```
<ul class="flights" id="f238226">
 <li id="tabS1" class="arrivals selected">
  <a href="/Reizigers/Vluchttijden/Aankomsttijden.htm" onclick="return selecttabA(1);">Aankomst</a>
 </li>
 <li id="tabS2" class="departures">
  <a href="/Reizigers/Vluchttijden/Vertrektijden.htm" onclick="return selecttabA(2);">Vertrek</a>
 </li>
</ul>
<li id="tabS1" class="arrivals selected"><a

<div id="tab1">
<h2>Aankomst</h2>
<form action="/Reizigers/Vluchttijden/Aankomsttijden.htm"  method="get"  name="adv_flight_search" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Schema</th>
      <th>Vlucht</th>
          <th>Herkomst</th>
      <th>Opmerkingen</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
              <tr class="mark">
              <td>13:15</td>
              <td>AF 8387</td>
              <td>Quito</td>
            <td>Geland</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current XPath expression:

```
"//ul[@class='flights']//tr"
```

Is looking for `ul` elements that have an attribute `class` whose value is "flights" and selects all their descendant elements `tr`.

Yet, it seems that what you are after is not inside `tr` elements, which would also imply that the data is inside a table, but in an unordered list. Try the following expression.

```
"//ul[@class='flights']/li"
```

If that does not help, you might have to reveal what exactly you'd like to find and show more HTML.

Comment: @Mathias.I provided some more HTML code. I would like to scrape the dynamic flight info that you see in the caroussel on schiphol.nl. The info I need is in the <td>, standard cell in the HTML table. I would like the arriving flights but also the departing ones (that are behind a different tab as you can see. <li id="tabS2" class="departures">. Hope my Q is clearer now. thnx

Comment: @Diederik That does not help I'm afraid. I still do not see 5 "arriving flights" in your HTML - mostly because I do not know what you mean by "arriving flights". There is only one table, with two `td` elements that could qualify as flight destinations. Is this what you mean? What does this unordered list have to do with the table that follows it?